# Mac book air is not turning on and getting cricket noise when press power button

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, power-management, power-mac

My Mac book is not turning on when pressing power button . I can hear a cricket sound when ever I press power button.
Initially it was turning on when I do SMC reset . But now power is full and getting green light when I plugin power cable. So if I do SMC reset now , I couldn't see the flickering from Amber to green . Now it's not working after SMC reset. Suggest me some solutions to turn on mac book air .

Comment: isn't this a static flash drive for air's?  it must be the heartsick fan on top of the CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chirps/Beeps might indicate a hardware failure on disk or RAM or the power supply. It likely needs to be serviced by either Apple or an authorized Apple repair center if it's under warranty. You can check the warranty and AppleCare coverage [here](https://checkcoverage.apple.com)

PS: If it's an older MacBook Air that is out of warranty or out of AppleCare coverage than a 3rd party repair might be the most cost effective.

Comment: This is a global site. Recommending a local dealer isn‘t all that helpful and may make your answer look like spam.

Comment: That was not my intention. I was trying convey the need for a quality component level hihgly skilled 3rd party repair center.

Comment: I‘m aware of that. Feel free to edit stuff in if I removed too much. Just don‘t mention any specific shops :-)